# Mongoose query user ids inside an array property

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a messaging app where a conversation model stores the participants of a unique conversation.

I am trying to query for a specific conversation where two userIds are inside the participant array but I get the error message *'Query filter must be an object, got an array '*.

I tried putting the array inside an object but it didn't work and not sure how to make this query work OR if there is a better way to perform this search.

What am I doing wrong?

MODEL

```js
const conversationSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    participants: [
      {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: `User`
      }
    ]
  }
)
```

EXPRESS ROUTE CODE

```js
  const existingConvo = await Conversation.findOne({
        participants: { $elemMatch: [msg.senderId, msg.recId] },
        // ^ Query filter must be an object, got an array 
      })
```

Comment: Try to use [$all](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) to replace $elemMatch and see if it can solve your issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use case should require a [$all](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) instead of `$elemMatch` since you require the `participants` array to contain both/all users in your query array.

Your code should be like this:

```js
const existingConvo = await Conversation.findOne({
    participants: { $all: [msg.senderId, msg.recId] }
})
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fG04s5PNRj3) for you to reference the behaviour of `$all` in native mongo query.